# Pencils of Circles

Tags: geometry

I want to solve an exercise regarding the connection between the projective model of möbius geometry and pencils of circles.

> Consider the projective model of two-dimensional Möbius geometry P($R^{3,1}$) where points outside the möbius quadric correspond to circles. Show that a projective line given by a two-dimensional subspace
>
> of signature $(+-)$ corresponds to a one-parameter family of circles all passing through the same two points (elliptic pencil).
>
> of of signature $(++)$ corresponds to a one-parameter family of circles that do not intersect each other at any point (hyberbolic pencil).
>
> of signature $(+0)$ corresponds to a one-parameter family of circles all tangent to each other at a single common point (parabolic pencil).
>
> Of which type is the family of orthogonal circles in each case?

I do know that circles in the extended euclidean plane $R^2 \cup$ ${\infty}$ correspond to hyperplanes in the projective space P($R^{3,1}$) intersecting the unit sphere $S^2$. Each hyperplane corresponds to a point outside $S^2$ where the point is orthogonal to the plane w.r.t the Lorentz inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

Given a two-dimensional subspace U of $R^{3,1}$ there are three possible signatures that can be obtained by restricting $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to U.

So each point [p] in the projective line P(U) indeed corresponds to a circle.

But I have some difficulty proving the claims since I do not see how the signature affects the pencil.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer just now. But I've doubts regarding the claims in the statement, so don't loose heart if you get different results. Can you picture your $S^2$ as a light cone in a relativistic [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space)? Do you have an intuition of what being orthogonal means in this space? Btw. it might help to more clearly distinguish between the circle itself (homogeneous vector outside $S^2$) and the set of points incident with the circle (orthogonal hyperplane intersected with $S^2$).